# Angular unit test failing when using (submit)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

Using Angular v4.4.4, I am saving a form using the `(submit)` event on the `<form>` element. On the live code everything works correctly. However, in the unit test clicking on a `<button>` does not trigger `(submit)` and the test fails. For example,

Component (pseudo-code):

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (submit)="onSave()">
            Your name: <input type="text" formControlName="name">
            <button id="saveButton">Save</button>
        </form>
    `
})
export class FooComponent {
    public formGroup: FormGroup;

    public onSave(): void {
        // save and route somewhere
    }
}
```

Unit test (pseudo-code):

```
describe('FooComponent', () => {
    let fixture, component, _router, routerSpy;

    beforeAll(done => (async() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        _router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);
        routerSpy = spyOn(_router, 'navigate');
        fixture.detectChanges();
    })().then(done).catch(done.fail));

    it('should save the form', () => {
        const saveButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#saveButton'));
        saveButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
        expect(routerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

        // the test fails because the form is not actually submitted
    });
});
```

I am certain the problem is with the `(submit)` event because if I remove it and move the `onSave()` call to a `(click)` on the button the unit test does work.

So this fails in a unit test:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (submit)="onSave()">
```

But this succeeds:

```
<button id="saveButton" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
```

What am I doing wrong in the spec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have no event handler on the button. That's why `triggerEventHandler` can't trigger any handler on the button. In your case you have to use `saveButton.nativeElement.click()` because now click event will be bubbled and `submit` event will be fired

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.